# Insert Current Date in ADL Gen2 (DataBricks)

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am new to Databricks, i have a requirement where in silver layer after transformation is happening i have to take the max(load_date) from my dataset and update that value in storage account (Transient folder). A .csv file is already available in the Transient folder where i have to overwrite the max(load_date) value every time my notebook runs.

for now i am doing it creating a empty Dataframe then assigning the max date and then loading it to the file but it seems not working that way.
Any idea to do it in a efficient way?

Comment: You need to explain what exactly you're doing (schema, code) and what exactly is the issue (errors or data got vs expected).

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty SQL table then assign the max date into the data frame by using the merge operation.

I have stored my Max date in the `kDF` data frame.

```
kDF.write.option("mergeSchema","true").format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable("test3")
```

[image]

After the merge operation, Max date will be stored in the `test3` table and stored in this location  `/mnt/defaultDatalake/filedemo`.

Now You can check the data:

```
df1 = spark.read.format("delta").option("header", "true").load("/mnt/defaultDatalake/filedemo")
display(df1)
```

[image]

Then perform the write operation with azure data lake gen2:

```
#Connect Gen2 with azure databricks

spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net",
  "Access_key"
)
```

Overwrite the data into Gen2

```
df1.coalesce(1).write.format('csv').mode("overwrite").save("abfss://demo12@vamblob.dfs.core.windows.net/vam")
```

[image]